# IntelliJ Java formatter align when multiline at asignment

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

how can I force IntelliJ Java formatter to keep code like this:

```java
boolean betweenKingLeftAndRookEmpty = 
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(59).isEmpty() &&
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(58).isEmpty() &&
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(57).isEmpty();
```

And not like this:

```java
boolean betweenKingLeftAndRookEmpty =
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(59).isEmpty() &&
                            board.getSquareAtPosition(58).isEmpty() &&
                            board.getSquareAtPosition(57).isEmpty();
```

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use comments to disable formatting for certain blocks of code like so:

```
...

//@formatter:off
boolean betweenKingLeftAndRookEmpty = 
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(59).isEmpty() &&
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(58).isEmpty() &&
                    board.getSquareAtPosition(57).isEmpty();
//@formatter:on

...
```

Anything before or after this block will be formatted, while anything inside will not. Granted, this method is incredibly inefficient if you need to apply it to multiple areas, but can prove useful if you have very few specific use cases for it.

Source: [Reformat code: Intellij IDEA Documentation#exclude_part_of_code](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#exclude_part_of_code)

Comment: That's an option, but a setting will be better

Comment: for sure! I hope there is one! :)